# Angular js how to pass data from Ajax to select option html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, ajax

I new in angular js, 
I have problem when I used ajax for on change on html of select option. I not sure what doing is right or wrong but what I trying is not result on UI and not errors in console log of browser also, it no effect.

This is my HTML

```
<select require="require" ng-model="getself_data" ng-change ="get_type(1)" ng-init="get_type(0)">
```

And this is my js

```
  $scope.get_type = function(){
       $http({
         method: "POST",
         url: 'getmydata'
        }).then(success, failed);
         function success(response) {
           console.log(response);
           if(response['data']['CODE']==="000"){
             var opt_data = "";
             var total_row = response['data']['DATA'].length;

             for (var i = 0; i < total_row; i++) {
               opt_data = "<option value='" + response['data']['DATA'][i]['ID'] +"'>" +response['data']['DATA'][i]['NAME'] +"</option>";
               }
             console.log(opt_data);

             $scope.getself_data = opt_data;
           }else{
             console.log(response);
           }
         };
         function failed(response) {
             console.log(response);
             alert('Error : ' + response);
         }
}
```

For result response from ajax is

```
{
   "CODE": "000",
    "DATA": [
        {
         "ID": "2",
         "NAME": "AAAA"
        },
        {
         "ID": "6",
         "NAME": "Test_name"
        }
      ]}
```

please help me to solve it

Comment: It seems to me that your are confusing the ng-model with the ng-options

Comment: shouldn't your `$http` request have the type `GET` instead? In fact `$http.get(url).then(...)` syntax is easier to follow

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are incorrectly generating the select options.

Your **get_type** function is binding what appears to be html to your scope's **getself_data** model. This is more of a jquery method of approach and not an angularjs method of approach. You need to let angularjs generate the HTML for you by giving it objects to work with.

Instead you need to rework your markup so that it keeps everything within angular. One option is to utilize the ngOptions directive, whose purpose is to dynamically generate a list **< option >** elements for the **< select >** element. You can read more about the ngOptions directive [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions).

```
<select ng-model="getself_data" ng-options="option.ID as option.NAME for option in response.data"></select>
```

With your markup configured this way you need to bind the result of your $http call to the scope. Since I elected to define my variables like so *for **option** in **response.DATA*** we need response.DATA to be bound to the scope.

```
 $scope.get_type = function(){
   $http({...}).then(success, failed);
     function success(response) {
       $scope.response = response['data'];

       //response.data will now have the two objects within your array, 
       //and therefore two option elements will be generated. One for each 
       // object within your data array. And the ID property will be bound 
       // to the option element's value property. And the label will use the 
       // NAME property.


     };
     function failed(response) {...}
}
```

Now through the magic of two-way binding in angularJs, your **$scope.getself_data** will now have the ID value of the selected option.